# Javascript get the value of all dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a table which has multiple dropdowns, inside each row

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr class= 'products'>
    <td>Gold</td>
    <td>
    <select onchange='get_all_products()'>
  <option value="25">Gold 1</option>
  <option value="27">Gold 2</option>
</select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class= 'products'>
    <td>Silver</td>
    <td>
    <select onchange='get_all_products()'>
  <option value="50">SILVER 1</option>
  <option value="476">SILVER 2</option>
</select>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class= 'products'>
    <td>Bronz</td>
    <td>
    <select onchange='get_all_products()'>
  <option value="71">BRONZ 1</option>
  <option value="89">BRONZ 2</option>
</select>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

on the `onchange` of each dropdown I want to get the value of all the dropdowns that are inside the class "products"  `<tr class="products">`

Comment: Where is the Jquery code ? Please edit question and show what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may go through all selects with using jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

  function get_all_products() {
    $('.products select').each(function (index, el) {
        console.log($(el).find('option:selected').text() + ' - ' + $(el).val());
    });
  };

</script>
```

Output:

```
Gold 2 - 27
SILVER 1 - 50
BRONZ 1 - 71
```